# GetTokenSecret value by dotnetopenauth

Tags: api, twitter, dotnetopenauth, tokenize

I tried to Get Token secret by using dotnetopenoauth.
I searched in it and find

> SimpleConsumerTokenManager

class which has

> GetTokenSecret()

which seems fine to me but could not making an object of it as it depend on "AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager"

could you please guide me if you know how can I initialize this class , or even is this the right way of getting secret token to make my twitter signature string

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth does not store token secrets. The SimpleConsumerTokenManager that you found is meant only for temporary storage of a single token and secret during authentication. The IConsumerTokenManager interface is how DNOA interacts with your app so that your app can store and retrieve tokens and secrets.

So in other words, I don't know why you're looking for a way to use DNOA for retrieving token secrets.